# How to force the user to press ctrl+alt+delete in order to log in to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, login

In order to log in to Windows, one needed to press ctrl+alt+delete. However, in Windows 10 I've noticed that this is no longer required - as soon as you press ctrl, the login screen is already shown.

There's a setting in user accounts I believe where you can toggle the requirement for ctrl+alt+delete to log in, but this toggles between ctrl+alt+delete-logon and auto-logon IIRC.

How do I change my Windows 10 so that I need to press ctrl+alt+delete again in order to log in? That is ctrl AND alt AND delete, not just ctrl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `secpol.msc`, then navigate to **Local Policies** -> **Security Options** -> and **Disable** `"Interactive Logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL"`